# Symbology Method. "Size" not showing up in "Method", QGIS 2.10.1

Tags: qgis, symbology

QGIS 2.10 is supposed to be able to allow you to use size instead of color for a gradient method, as seen here: http://anitagraser.com/2015/06/21/qgis-2-10-symbology-feature-preview/.
However, I get no such option. The "Method" drop down only contains color. Do I need to activate this option somewhere else? I am in QGIS 2.10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Size* method for the graduated symbology **only applies to Line and Point shapefiles**.

It does not apply to polygons, which is probably why you are only seeing *Color* as the only option.